# Getting started with rails 6: how to start a blank new rails 6 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to rebuild one of my old rails apps using the latest rails version available at github/rails/rails

How do I start off with the "rails new ...." ?

Comment: Didn't `rails new yourappname` worked?

Comment: that gives me a rails 4 application for some reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems this can be as easy as this:

```
$ mkdir example
$ cd example
$ echo "source 'https://rubygems.org'" >> Gemfile
$ echo "gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git'" >> Gemfile
$ bundle install
Fetching https://github.com/rails/rails.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 12.3.1

$ bundle exec rails new . --dev --force
       exist
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
       force  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."

$ bundle exec rails server -d
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.0.alpha application starting in development
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
```

UPDATE (2020):
It turns out, the stable branch has nearly all the goodies found in the HEAD, but actually usable in production. So since then, I've [modified](https://www.sam-we.com/posts/Install_edge_rails.html) the solution and nowadays I use these steps:

```
##
# Install edge rails
#
cd /tmp
git clone -b 6-0-stable --single-branch https://github.com/rails/rails
cd /tmp/rails
LATEST_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD) 
bundle update --bundler
bundle install
cd /tmp/rails/railties/exe
bundle exec rails --version
bundle exec rails new /tmp/your-app-name --dev --database=postgresql --force
cd /tmp/your-app-name
bundle exec rails --version # verify
# Without this, you'll get the error: The path does not exist.
cd /tmp/your-app-name
s1='gem .rails.,.*'
s2="gem 'rails', git: 'https:\/\/github.com\/rails\/rails.git', ref: '$LATEST_COMMIT'"
perl -pi.bak -e "s/$s1/$s2/" Gemfile
bundle install
```

Comment: Almost worked, just had some problems with `webpack` & `webpacker` ... had to run :  `bundle pack` and  `bundle install --path vendor/cache` to solve it

Comment: must be a new thing

Comment: Well actually the problem was I was running `bundle exec rails new anyProjectName --dev --force` inside a folder with the first commands you propose, instead of `bundle exec rails new . --dev --force`. Would love that rails be smarter this time :(

Answer (score 4):

Install rails 6 (6.0.0 as per latest update) in a directory with 
`gem install rails -v 6.0.0` .
After that you can run `gem list rails` to check installed versions of rails.

You should see something like below

`rails (6.0.0)` 
or
`rails (6.0.0, 5.2.3, 5.2.2)` 
if you have multiple versions installed.

now create your new app by

`rails _6.0.0_ new newapp`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
before you will follow, check @Rajan Verma's comment

The latest version of rails available as of now is `6.1.0.alpha`. You can start the new app with it like this:

```sh
rails new MyApp --skip-bundle
```

then go to Gemfile and change:

```rb
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3' # or whatever version you have
```

to:

```
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
```

or if you want to start with the latest **stable** version, (as of now) change it to:

```rb
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0.rc1'
```

Then and run `bundle install`

[Here](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/) you can find more details about latest releases.

Comment: Changing gemfile version doesn't gives the same app directory structure as of version 6.  That's lot of manual task to do . Its recommended to start with a boilerplate of version 6.